# Print function for Tower of Hanoi in java

Tags: java

I am supposed to display every move of my Tower of Hanoi algorithm in the console. I've managed to get the program to give me the number of steps it takes to finish the algorithm with n disks. Even if that is probably of no use for this task.

each disk b shalll be represented with 2b-1 hashes ('#') and the steps should be divided by '---'

This is how that should look like for n=3.

```
  #
 ###
#####
---
 ###
#####               #
---
#####    ###        #
---
          #
#####    ###
---
          #
         ###     #####
---

 #       ###      #####
---
                   ###
#                 #####
---
                    #
                   ###
                  #####
```

And this is my algorithm:

```
public static long move(int n, HanoiStack a, HanoiStack c, HanoiStack b){   
    long count = 0;

    if(n > 0){              
        count = count + move(n - 1, a, b, c);
        c.hanoiPush(a.pop());                  
        count = count + move(n - 1, b, c, a);

    }
    if(n >= 1){
        count++;           // because of recursivity
    }
    return count;
}
```

I am greatful for any hints, because I don't have any clue how to start with this.

Comment: If you search through stackoverflow questions there are plenty of hanoi examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like one of my uni assignments, except the professor wrote the printing functions for us.

Generally its a good idea to write a visualizer class or a printer class for these kind of problems to visualise.

I suggest you write a `print_game_state(stack a, stack b, stack c)` function rather then build it into your algorithm because that will confuse things.

I don't know what type of object HanoiStack is but you would get each element like this:

```
//pseudo code
print a[0] + "\t" + b[0] + "\t" + c[0];
print a[1] + "\t" + b[1] + "\t" + c[1];
print a[2] + "\t" + b[2] + "\t" + c[2];
```

I.e. print the row of each stack like a printer would print onto a page.

You could do a `print_row(int n)` function which just prints the bottom, top, or whichever row is passed to it and call that recursively to make it even more simple.